# How can I refactor these wrapper methods to get rid of duplicated code?

Tags: java, refactoring, gson, code-duplication

The following two methods are used to wrap deserialization using Google Gson:

```
public static <T> T Deserialize(String jsonData, Type t) {
    T obj = null;

    try {
        obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, t);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    return obj;
}

public static <T> T Deserialize(String jsonData, Class<T> toClass) {
    T obj = null;

    try {
        obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, toClass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    return obj;
}
```

They are almost identical, but I can't figure out a smart way to get rid of the duplicated code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd be careful removing one of the methods. Look at the JavaDoc: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class). I'm pretty sure they had a very good reason to provide two methods, one for generics and another one for non-generic types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Class` implements the interface `Type`, so it looks like only having the first method should be sufficient.

**EDIT:** actually it looks like these methods are implemented separately for a reason. At least read [the javadoc](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Class%29) to understand why before refactoring. Thanks to home for pointing this out.

Comment: Should probably have known that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Type` is an interface implemented by `Class`, so you could get rid of the second method completely.

Comment: `Class` is a class, so technically `Type` isn't a superinterface, it just implements it.

Comment: No, the `fromJson` method is overloaded to take either a class or a type object. Since java does not dispatch on the dynamic type of the argument, that would always invoke the overload taking a`Type` argument.